# Command to move cursor to matched pattern in vim

Tags: vim

I know `/dog<CR>` will place my cursor at the first instance of `dog`, however I'm not getting the same effect when using a command.

I've tried the following:

`:command FindDog /dog`

`:command FindDog exec '/dog'`

`:command FindDog :normal /dog<CR>` (this one seems to just hang until I Ctrl-C)

Something tells me I'm doing this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to know that, `:/dog<cr>` works too. It does the same as `/dog`. You don't have to call the `search()` function. If you would like to create your own command, you can just do for example:

```
:command FindDog :/dog
```

Comment: this is great to know and sheds some light on exactly what i was misusing about the syntax, I think. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. `call search('dog')` did the trick. I will let someone with more than a week of vim decide if this question would help anyone else or not.